# Subtracting 52 weeks from a set date

Tags: sql

Could anyone please assist, I would like to streamline a manual process of calculating 52 weeks retrospectively from a set date in SQL.

This is what I have however, I cannot get this to work

```
DECLARE @StartDate StartDate = '2020-02-03'

SELECT @StartDate 'StartDate',
           DATEADD(week,-51,@StartDate()) 'EndDate'
```

Comment: What issue you are facing? What you are expecting? what is your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I resolved some syntax issue from your script. Hope this will help you to achieve your required output.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04fc14bd0645dcde13bd0bf34b7b715d)

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
SET @StartDate = '20200203'

SELECT @StartDate 'StartDate', DATEADD(week,-51,@StartDate) 'EndDate'
```

Or you can use your DATE format as well as below-

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
SET @StartDate = '2020-02-03'

SELECT @StartDate 'StartDate', DATEADD(week,-51,@StartDate) 'EndDate'
```

Comment: Thank you, and how would I get this out of date in the following format "YYYY-MM-DD"?

Comment: SELECT @StartDate 'StartDate', convert(varchar,(DATEADD(week,-51,@StartDate)),23) 'EndDate'

Comment: @QuintinSmith this should also work for the format "YYYY-MM-DD". Just check the DEMO

Answer (score 0):

You also can try this :

```
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
    SET @StartDate = '2020/02/03'

SELECT @StartDate 'StartDate', convert(varchar,(@StartDate - (51*7)),23)  'EndDate'
```

Comment: **THANK YOU** Much appreciated, I will comment should this be resolved.